# Check if screen saver is running in Mac using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

Is there a way to check if the screen saver is running using AppleScript?

Currently I'm using the following AppleScript to start the screen saver:

```
tell application "System Events" 
    start current screen saver
end tell
```

I found this [script](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2453901?tstart=0) but I don't know if that's correct or how to write that into my script.

What I want is something like this:

```
tell application "System Events" 
    if screen saver is not activated then
        start current screen saver
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late now but for others trying similar things.

I used the following recently in a shell script linked to a cronjob.

```
# check if screen saver is running
saverActive=$(osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\"" -e "get running of screen saver preferences" -e "end tell")
if [ "$saverActive" = "true" ]; then
  echo "Screen saver is running"
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to stop current screen saver"
  osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to start current screen saver"
else
  echo "Screen saver is not running"
fi
```

This script was used in the context of periodically changing the screensaver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
tell application "System Events"
    if not (running of screen saver preferences) then start current screen saver
end tell
```